# JTest 9.5. How to execute preparation actions before each unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm using JTest 9.5. I wanted to ask whether there is possibility to perform same preparation routine before each unit test, just like I did it in JUnit with `@Before` and `@After` annotations? If yes, then how? Let's say I have following unit test class in JTest:

```
public class TestArrayFileManager extends PackageTestCase {

    FileManager fileMngr;

    public TestArrayFileManager(String name) 
    {
        super(name);
    }

    public Class getTestedClass() 
    {
        return FileManager.class;
    }

    public void testFileManager1() throws Throwable 
    {
        final String fileName = "InputFile.txt";
        fileMngr = new FileManager(fileName);
        fileMngr.doResetFile();
        fileMngr.doReplaceNthElement(0, 3);
        fileMngr.doReplaceNthElement(1, 9);
        assertEquals(3, fileMngr.doReadNthElement(0L)); 
    }

    public void testFileManager2() throws Throwable 
    {
        final String fileName = "InputFile.txt";
        fileMngr = new FileManager(fileName);
        fileMngr.doResetFile();
        fileMngr.doReplaceNthElement(0, 3);
        fileMngr.doReplaceNthElement(1, 9);
        assertEquals(9, fileMngr.doReadNthElement(1L)); 
    }
    }
```

Notice how i keep repeating same preparation code. How can I perform it before each test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fount the methods I have to add in order to achieve preparation and ending tasks before each unit test. These are the methods I found in generated unit tests file and they are working:

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    /*
     * Add any necessary initialization code here (e.g., open a socket).
     * Call Repository.putTemporary() to provide initialized instances of
     * objects to be used when testing.
     */
    // jtest.Repository.putTemporary("name", object);
}

/**
 * Used to clean up after the test. This method is called by JUnit after
 * each of the tests have been completed.
 * 
 * @see junit.framework.TestCase#tearDown()
 * @author Parasoft Jtest 9.5
 */
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    try {
        /*
         * Add any necessary cleanup code here (e.g., close a socket).
         */
    } finally {
        super.tearDown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[JTest complements and extends JUnit](http://www.technology.heartland.edu/courses/Computer%20Science/Programming/Java%20Courses/JTest%20User%27s%20Guide/junit.htm) which means that it is not there to provide the features of JUnit. You will have to use JTest with Junit in order to achieve what you want.

You can [use existing JUnit test cases with JTest](http://www.technology.heartland.edu/courses/Computer%20Science/Programming/Java%20Courses/JTest%20User%27s%20Guide/testclas.htm#1002226) which will provide both setUp and tearDown methods using `@Before` and `@After` annotations.

If you want to use a JUnit Test Class with Jtest, you need to:

- Include the junit.jar file on your CLASSPATH.
- Make sure Jtest knows how to locate the Test Class (as described in Loading Test Classes below).

After you perform these steps, Jtest will use the JUnit Test Class when you run your test in the normal manner.